# Circular dependency issue within Angular Library

Tags: angular, circular-dependency, angular-library, angular14

I am facing an issue with Angular circular dependency. To explain, I have a component let us say DynamicForm Component, which utilizes a directive (dynamicField). The directive in turn creates component instances of various components based on a component type that is provided. Within the directive, I have multiple specific components which uses the DynamicFormComponent in the template through a selector(). As a result a circular dependency is getting created.

Below is the DynamicFormComponent template code.

dynamic-form.component.html

```
<section>
    <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
        <div class="dynamic-form">
            <ng-template dynamicField 
                [field]="field" 
                [control]="formGroup" 
                (updateValueChange)="updateValueChange($event)">
            </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

where the fields array looks like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "input1",
    "type": "select",
    "label": "Select a value",        
  },
  {
    "name": "input2",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Enter a value",        
  },
  {
    "name": "input3",
    "type": "multiTab",
    "label": "",     
  }

]
```

Below is the dynamicField code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicField]'
})
export class DynamicFieldDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() field! : FieldMapper;
  @Input() control! : AbstractControl | null;
  @Output() updateValueChange = new EventEmitter();
  componentInstance!: ComponentRef<any>;
  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  ) { }

  componentMapper: { [key: string]: any } = {
    input: InputComponent,
    select: SelectComponent,
    multiTab: MultiTabComponent,
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentInstance = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      this.componentMapper[this.field.type]
    );
    this.componentInstance.instance.field = this.field;
    this.componentInstance.instance.control = this.control;
    this.componentInstance.instance.updateValueChange.subscribe((res: EmitField) => {
      this.updateValueChange.emit(res);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.componentInstance.destroy();
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
  }
}
```

and the MultiTabComponent template is as follows

```
<section class="multi-tab">
  <form [formGroup]="multiTabForm">
    <mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="currentTabIndex">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of orderedMultiTabs; let index = index;">
        <mat-tab>
          <ng-template matTabLabel>
            {{tab?.label}}
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template matTabContent>
            <dynamic-form [formControlName]="tab.name" [fields]="tab.fields"></dynamic-form>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </form>
</section>
```

This is creating a circular dependency for dynamic-form -> directive -> multi-tab -> dynamic-form.
This is causing the following error when I build the library.
"One or more import cycles would need to be created to compile this component, which is not supported by the current compiler configuration."
Can some one help me overcome this issue?